# Cannot find main class to run .jar, from Sbt-Assembly

Tags: java, scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

**MyProject/build.sbt**

```
    mainClass in assembly := Some("Boot")
```

**MyProject/Boot.scala**

```
    package src.main.myproject

    object Boot extends App { ... }
```

**Other Project Files**:

```
    MyProject/src/main/scala/myproject/someFile.scala
```

Running the jar returns the error:

```
    Error: Could not find or load main class Boot
```

Is there a problem with my project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Boot` is in src.main.myproject, so the mainClass should be `src.main.myproject.Boot`

Off topic in terms of the question, but it doesn't seem conventional that src.main is part of your package structure though, normally scala src directory of sbt is set to src/main/scala